# Can we clarify the 'career' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Having a *brief* look through the [career](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag, it is clear that there is some severe usage issues. *With 61 tagged questions, I count only 19 that have not been closed*. It appears to have been over 2 years since [somebody asked an on-topic question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/75774/will-unity-skills-be-transferable), using this tag. I still think the *'on-topicness'* of some of the open questions is questionable, but I digress.

It seems that some of these questions have still received good feedback, despite being closed. I do not think we should *delete* the tag. That said, it seems evident that users who use this tag are far more likely to be asking a question that is *off-topic*.

Can we get a good canon usage guideline for this tag, so users understand when to use it, and why many of the questions that *might* use it would be off-topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the tag is fine. In fact I think removing it or otherwise prohibiting its use runs directly counter to the current stated topic of the site. The [Help Center](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) explicitly lists "game industry (careers, trends, technology, etc)" as a valid topic.

Just because we haven't seen any questions in the tag recently that we also consider on-topic for other reasons does not mean the tag is, itself, an issue. And removing it would imply a larger discussion about whether or not the help center needs to be revised.

I can certainly envision a future, although I don't necessary endorse or decry it, where we relax certain other existing guidelines to permit discussion of career history or advice.

I do think it needs a excerpt and wiki though. I have tentatively seeded the tag excerpt as follows:

> Career refers to the progression, over time, of one's chosen profession. Questions using this tag should be related to such topics, but note that opinion-oriented discussions, such as solicitations for career advice are off-topic. See the full tag wiki for more details.

And the wiki as:

> While questions concerning the game industry, including topics related to one's career, are broadly considered on-topic here, many career-related questions tend concern career *advice*, which can be heavily opinion-based and subject to extensive discussion and are thus off-topic by their nature.
>
> Depending on your specific question, you may be able to find the assistance you need on another StackExchange site, in our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development), or a discussion forum such as [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net).

I believe this adequately covers the current de facto state of the tag. If anybody has suggestions for how it could be improved (and cannot improve it themselves due a lack of reputation), please comment here.

Comment: Awesome. That's exactly the sort of guideline users need.

Answer (score -1):

I think we should keep the tag for legacy reason, and put a warning right in the *excerpt*. The only *Usage guidance (excerpt)* I could see fit for this tag would be something along the lines:

> If you tag your question with this, it will most likely be closed. Sorry. Questions related to jobs in the video game development industry. Questions about this are generally considered off-topic for this site as based on opinion.

With the full description:

> The scope of the site has changed since its creation; as time went by, opinion based question became off-topic, but they were not deleted for historical reasons.

Comment: Note that I say *most* questions are closed. Not *all* of them. Its not that such questions are *automatically* off topic, it is that users seem to find it difficult asking ontopic questions.

Comment: Also, for clarification, the *opinion based questions* close reason is universal. Its not something we decided on, here, and we should not give the impression that we can discuss *removing* this close reason, here.

Comment: We can, however, decide where we consider the boundaries for "primarily opinion based" to be; there is certainly precedent for SE sites that have significantly more room for opinion and discussion. I don't really think it's needed here, but it's not impossible for us to decide to relax our stance on particular classes of opinion.